# Inserto into ( Select ) with not auto increment

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Have two tables

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TABELAA]
(
    [ID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [PodatakA] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [PodatakB] [nvarchar](50) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_TABELAA] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
                   WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                         IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                         ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TABELAB]
(
    [PodatakX] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [PodatakY] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I need to insert value from tabelaB to tabelaA with autogenerating ID in tabelaA so I need something like this. But this would be great if there is only one row. I'm talking about thousands of rows where it should auto generate id exact like AutoIncrement (1)

Useless try where I think I should use OVER

```
INSERT INTO TABELAA 
    SELECT 
        (SELECT MAX(id) + 1 FROM TabelaA) AS Id, * 
    FROM
        tabelaB
```

Comment: Then why not define it as `auto_increment`? why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @Rahul Its complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the `IDENTITY`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TABLAAA](
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,  -- NOT NULL is handled by PRIMARY KEY
    [PodatakA] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [PodatakB] [nvarchar](50) NULL
);

INSERT INTO TABLEAA (PodatakA, PodatakB)
    SELECT PodatakA, PodatakB
    FROM TABLEBB;
```

Comment: Your constraint definition doesn't specify a column.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Rahul's comment and Gordon that if you can modify your schema it would make the most sense to add an Identity Column.  However if you cannot you can still accomplish what you want using a couple of methods.

One method is get the `MAX` `ID` of `TableAA` and then add a `ROW_NUMBER()` to it like so:

```
INSERT INTO TableAA (ID, PodatakA, PodatakB)
SELECT
    m.CurrentMaxId +  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    ,b.PodatakA
    ,b.PodatakB
FROM
    TableAB b
    CROSS APPLY (
       SELECT ISNULL(MAX(Id),0) as CurrentMaxId
   FROM
      TableAA) m
```

**Again this would be work around the most ideal solution is to specify IDENTITY**

Also this is susceptible to problems due to simultaneous writes and other scenarios in a heavy traffic DB.